# Overlay a border/image in Flash/Firefox that ignores mouse clicks

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, firefox

I'm building a flash app that will go full screen. I need to ensure it's usable at a variety of resolutions.

While I'm designing the app, I want to overlay the guidelines you see here:
http://browsersize.googlelabs.com/

I can overlay them fine, but the problem is I now can't interact with the app, because when I click on some part of the UI, it thinks I'm clicking on the image, since it's technically in front. I want the image to be in the front at a visual level, but without it having any bearing on the keyboard/mouse interaction with the app.

My fall back is to create a series of 1pixel wide lines, which will still be in the foreground mouse/keyboard wise, but I can cope with losing that much interaction ability.

Alternatively, is there some way to strap these guide markers on at the browser(firefox) level?

Answer (score 4):

I believe this sounds like a "mousechildren", or possibly a "mouseEnabled" property issue. There is an article about it here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS948100b6829bd5a63821f6a2126681c5c57-8000.html

Basically, by setting the mouseEnabled and mouseChildren properties to false, you can prevent your mouse events from bubbling when you click on a disabled MovieClip which has been placed on top of a mouseEnabled MovieClip.

```
 myMovieClip.mouseEnabled = false;
 myMovieClip.mouseChildren = false;
```

The mouseChildren part is important, since it will tell AS3 to ignore all of the elements INSIDE of the MovieClip, while mouseEnabled will make the MovieClip itself ignore the mouse events (but not necessarily the enclosed children of the MovieClip).

Hope this helps.